# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with service worker in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

I have a very simple service worker to add offline support. The fetch handler looks like

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  var url = event.request.url;
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
    //var cacheResponse: Response = response.clone();
    //caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.offline).then((cache: Cache) => {
    //  cache.put(url, cacheResponse).catch(() => {
    //    // ignore error
    //  });
    //});
    return response;
 }).catch(function () {
    // check the cache
    return getCachedContent(event.request);
}));
```

});

Intermittently we are seeing a net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error for a particular script we load into the page when online. The error is not coming from the server as the service worker is picking up the file from the browser cache. Chrome's network tab shows the service worker has successfully fetched the file from the disk cache but the request from the browser to the service worker shows as (failed)

Does anyone know the underlying issue causing this? Is there a problem with my service worker implementation?

Comment: I don't think that this is related to your service worker. Can you confirm that you see the same behavior in an Incognito window, which will have a fresh browser cache and all extensions disabled?

Comment: I had the same problem using Incognito. It also stops happening if I remove the service worker. It seems to happen most frequently with large script files on slow networks (setting the network to Slow 3G in dev tools makes it happen almost all the time). I've reduced the impact of it by unbundling some of my files and reloading the script by injecting a script tag if required

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to a bug in Chrome (and potentially other browsers as well) that could result in a garbage collection event removing a reference to the response stream while it's still being read.

Its fix in Chrome is being tracked at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=934386.